# Python function to find indexes of 1s in binary array and

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array which looks like this

```
[1, 0, 1 , 0 , 0, 1]
```

And I want to get those indexes that have 1 in it.
So here I would get an array of `[0, 2 , 5]`
and then based on it I would create a new array that takes these numbers and exponantiate 2 with them
So the end array is

```
[2**0, 2**2, 2**5]
```

Is there a way to write it as shortly as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use enumerate in a list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 0, 1 , 0 , 0, 1]
b = [2**idx for idx, v in enumerate(a) if v]
b
```

#### output:

```
[1, 4, 32]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one compact way -

```
2**np.where(a)[0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [83]: a = np.array([1, 0, 1 , 0 , 0, 1])

In [84]: 2**np.where(a)[0]
Out[84]: array([ 1,  4, 32])
```

Answer (score 3):

There is  `np.where`, `np.argwhere`, `np.nonzero` and `np.flatnonzero`. Take your pick.

`np.where` and `np.nonzero` are as far as I know equivalent, only there is also a three argument version of where that does something different. `np.argwhere` is the transpose and `np.flatnonzero` gives flat indices.